# How to add all links to images or voucher we send via email in Drupal 7?

Tags: html, email, module, drupal-7, hyperlink

I am new to Drupal, so can any one tell me, how to add all links to images or voucher we send via email in Drupal 7.

Currently, I am using HTML Mail module to send emails, and I am able to send images but they are not linked with its page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know a lot about drupal either yet, but I have noticed there is a plug-in for Elastic Email (http://elasticemail.com) - http://drupal.org/project/elastic_email and I have been using Elastic Email with great success as it is very inexpensive, so maybe this plug-in would have some answers for you.